# Stripping all elements except one in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to remove all elements from XML except content of element called <source>. E.g.:

```
<root>
 <a>This will be stripped off</a>
 <source>But this not</source>
</root>
```

After XSLT:

```
But this not
```

I have tried this but with no luck (no output):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="source">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**From comments**:

> In my real XML I have the source
>   element in different namespace. I need
>   to google how to create a match
>   pattern for element in different
>   namespace. I would like to put each
>   extracted string also to newline ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not far off. The reason you're not getting any output is because your root match-all template isn't recursing but just terminating so you need to put an `apply-templates` call inside it. The following stylesheet gives the expected output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="source">
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that I've changed the output mode to `text` and the `source` template to simply output the textual value of the node, because it looks like you want text and not XML output.

Comment: I forgot to remark that my source elements are not in the root. They are deep (like on 5th level or something). I have tried match="//source" but with no luck :-(

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "no output"? I tested it using the Visual Studio XSLT editor and it definitely produces the output "But this not" when given the source document.

Comment: The `<source>` elements don't need to be at the root with this stylesheet; it will traverse the entire XML structure until it finds them.

Comment: You are right. It works with the example above. In my real XML I have the source element in different namespace. I need to google how to create a match pattern for element in different namespace. THANK YOU.

Comment: I would like to put each extracted string also to newline ;-)

Comment: I have used xsl:text with a space :-D

Comment: @lzap - in order to select any `source` element, regardless of the namespace, you could use this: `match="*[local-name()='source']"`

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, the sortest solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ex="http://example.org">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
    <xsl:template match="ex:source">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<root xmlns="http://example.org">
    <a>This will be stripped off</a>
    <source>But this not</source>
</root>
```

Output:

```
But this not
```